# Making a dynamic 2D array from a struct

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

If I have a struct with a few ints, bools & chars like below. Is it possible to create a 2D array of that struct, dynamically?

```
struct Matrix
{
  bool status;
  int x;
  int y;
  char display;
};


int main()
{
int a, b;

cin >> a >> b ;

Matrix array[a][b];
}
```

Such that I would later be able to write:

```
for (int i = 0; i<a; i++)
{
        for (int j = 0; j<b; j++) 
        {
            array[i][j].display = 'x';
            array[i][j].status = true;
        }
}
```

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<Matrix>>`.

Comment: Name of your struct is misleading BTW.

Comment: `Matrix array[a][b];` is not standard C++. But VLA extension.

Comment: Or if you want contiguous storage, you can instead define your own 2D array class backed by a 1D array of elements and storing dimensions.
If `b` is known at compile-time, then you can instead use `std::vector<std::array<Matrix, b>>`.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<Matrix>>` made great work. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Funnily enough, this is where C outperforms C++: C can handle true VLA types since C99 while C++ doesn't offer anything close to that. So the following is valid C code: `int a = ..., b = ...; Matrix (*array)[b] = malloc(a*sizeof(*array)); for(int i = 0; i < a; i++) for(int j = 0; j < b; j++) array[i][j] = (Matrix){ .status = false, .x = j, .y = i, .display = 42 };`